# Длинная шапка сайта

Tags: html, css

Как сделать длинную шапку для сайта только не картинкой. Просто сплошной синий цвет.

Answer (score 3):

Вот Вам рабочий пример - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/25StW/

```
<div class="header">Шапка сайта</div>

.header {
   width: 100%;
   background: blue;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   font: bold 25px Arial;
}
```

**Вот Вам отличный учебный сайт - http://htmlbook.ru/ (чтобы не задавали таких вопросов...)**

Comment: Как бы такую шапку и я сделать могу ))) Но она не прижата к верху

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду?

Возможно у Вас не убраны дефолтные стили. Чтобы это исправить, перед правилом CSS напишите следующее:

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

Вот пример = http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/25StW/2/

Comment: Если опять не то, то давайте Ваш код посмотрим. Выложите на http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Спс всё робит у меня ещё вопрос как прижать элемент к низу?

Comment: Какой элемент и к низу чего? 

Если необходимо прижать footer к низу страницы, то вот вам урок на эту тему - http://zvirec.com/view_post.php?id=50

Comment: А блин ваш код который шапка это текст контролирует размер блока а мне нужно что бы он был не зависим от текста.

Comment: В таком случае, задайте ему фиксированный размер, например вот так:

    height: 100px;

Comment: Всё робит  спс

Answer (score 0):

height еще добавить и все будет класс)

Comment: А что бы тему не создовать как сделать кнопку отображаемую и в IE

Comment: @Vlmake , может хватит говорить загадками?

Какую Вам нужно сделать кнопку и в каком IE?

C Вас HTML и CSS код кнопки, и версии браузеров, в которых данная кнопка должна корректно отображаться.

Comment: ТАк мне и нужен код кнопки который отображаеться во всех браузерах адекватно.
Цвета я сам поменяю

Comment: Ну вот например - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/6eksd/4/ будет отображаться везде одинаково!

    <a href="#">КНОПКА</a>


    a {
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 5px 20px;
       background: red;
       color: #fff;
       border: 1px solid #fff;
       text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {background: #000; }